# Redis ignores maxmemory setting

Tags: memory, redis

Redis has the following settings:

"**config get maxmemory**"

```
1) "maxmemory"
2) "2147483648"
```

(which is 2G)

But when I do "**info**"

```
used_memory:6264349904
used_memory_human:5.83G
used_memory_rss:6864515072
```

Clearly it ignores all the settings... Why?

P.S.

"**config get maxmemory-policy**" shows:

```
1) "maxmemory-policy" 
2) "volatile-ttl"
```

and: "**config get maxmemory-samples**" shows:

```
1) "maxmemory-samples" 
2) "3"
```

What means, they should expire keys with the nearest expiration date...

Answer (score 3):

Do you have expiration settings on all your keys? volatile-ttl will only remove keys with an expiration set. This should be in your info output.

If you don't have expiration ttls set try allkeys-lru or allkeys-random for your policy.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://redis.io/topics/faq

> You can also use the "maxmemory" option in the config file to put a limit to the memory Redis can use. If this limit is reached Redis will start to reply with an error to write commands (but will continue to accept read-only commands).

Comment: According to: config get maxmemory-policy
1) "maxmemory-policy"
2) "volatile-ttl"
and: config get maxmemory-samples
1) "maxmemory-samples"
2) "3"
They should expire keys with the nearest expiration date...